# Error: Call to a member function setActive() on bool in /var/www/html/project.local/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php:26

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, php, custom-admin-grid

**showing this error while clicking on a menu item created for a grid, the code below is my controller**

```
   <?php
namespace Vendor\Grid\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid;

class index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context        $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Grid List page.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Vendor_Grid::menu_id');
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Certificate Grid List'));

        return $resultPage;
    }

    /**
     * Check Grid List Permission.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Vendor_Grid::menu_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: please share proper code

Comment: code updated, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you don't have a `menu.xml` file properly created. The class that is throwing the error, calls a block called `menu` that refers to the `menu.xml` file.

class Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page::setActiveMenu

```
$menuBlock = $this->layout->getBlock('menu');
$menuBlock->setActive($itemId);
```

Please check the ‘menu.xml’ file and share code, also verify that you have added menu.xml on correct path.